# how to fetch data from two collection in arangodb

Tags: arangodb, aql

my project backend is arangodb. I have two collections named "test" and "demo". i need to fetch data from both these tables. my data is like this:

test

```
[
  {
    "firstName": "abc",
    "lastName": "pqr",
    "company": "abc Industries",
    "id": "1234"
  },
  {
    "firstName": "xyz",
    "lastName": "qwe",
    "company": "xyz Industries",
    "id": "5678"
  }
]
```

demo

```
[
  {
    "clientId": "1234",
    "subject": "test",
    "message": "testing",
    "priority": "High",
    "status": "closed",
    "id": "111111"
  },
  {
    "clientId": "1234", 
    "subject": "hiii",
    "message": "demo",
    "priority": "High",
    "status": "closed",
    "id": "222222"
  },
]
```

in this id of the test is same as clientid of the demo. i need to select data from the table that is data of the client "1234". how can i implement this using AQL(arango query language). i am new to arango. any suggestion will highly appreciable.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with [joins](https://docs.arangodb.com/3.1/AQL/Examples/Join.html#joins) or [subqueries](https://docs.arangodb.com/3.1/AQL/Examples/CombiningQueries.html#combining-queries).

A solution with a subqueries would look like:

```
FOR t IN test
  FILTER t.id == @client
  RETURN { 
    test: t,
    demo: (FOR d IN demo
             FILTER d.clientId == @client
             RETURN d)
  }
```

The `@client` is a [bind parameter](https://docs.arangodb.com/3.1/AQL/Fundamentals/BindParameters.html) which contains your value `1234`.

The result is:

```
[
  {
    "test": {
      "_key": "140306",
      "_id": "test/140306",
      "_rev": "_Urbgapq---",
      "company": "abc Industries",
      "firstName": "abc",
      "id": "1234",
      "lastName": "pqr"
    },
    "demo": [
      {
        "_key": "140233",
        "_id": "demo/140233",
        "_rev": "_UrbfyAm---",
        "clientId": "1234",
        "id": "222222",
        "message": "demo",
        "priority": "High",
        "status": "closed",
        "subject": "hiii"
      },
      {
        "_key": "140200",
        "_id": "demo/140200",
        "_rev": "_UrbfjfG---",
        "clientId": "1234",
        "id": "111111",
        "message": "testing",
        "priority": "High",
        "status": "closed",
        "subject": "test"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. in  this query i got an error Bind Parameter: ["client"] not defined.

Comment: You have to define the parameter `client`. In the WebUi you can see bind parameters on the right site of the page `queries`.

Answer (score 0):

```
For t in test
for d in demo 
filter t.id == d.clientId
filter t.id == @client
return {t,d}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
FOR collection IN [test,demo]
FOR x IN collection
RETURN x
```